# Retrieving Inline Edit In Separate PHP File Using Jquery/Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have list of records listed using while loop in index.php from mysql db

```
   <?php 
        include 'db.php';
        $sql = "select * from sections";
        $data = $con->query($sql);
        $str='';
        if($data->num_rows>0)
        {
            while( $row = $data->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
            $str.=" "?>
            <div>
                <div id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
                    <div>
                        <a class="ajaxload" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
                            <?php echo $row['name'];?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <span>
                        <a class='ajaxedit' data-id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value='Edit'>EDIT</a>
                        <a class='ajaxdelete' idd='<?php echo $row['id'];?>' value='Delete'>DELETE</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } } else { $str .= "<p style='text-align:left;'>No Data Available</p>"; } echo $str; ?>
```

Here in index.php file im displaying all records with name and edit/delete buttons

**Edit.php**

In edit.php file i want to retrieve the particular record with name and edit/delete buttons using jquery/ajax

**for example**

if i click on ABC name record i should get only

**ABC     edit delete**

if i click on XYZ name record i should get only

**XYZ     edit delete**

in edit.php file where im performing my Updation operation

Please Any help is appreciated Thanks!!

Comment: For this you have to call ajax to retrieve data from another page or you can use get data from particular row using jquery and filling in form using jquery

Comment: @Rutunjsheladiya Thank You For ur suggestion it would be helpful if u please post any example reference link so that i could follow it up n implement in my work Thanks!!!

Comment: you have to call ajax with id on your php page and retrieve and parse their response at your current page 
after that you have to replace your div using textbox with value and edit button with update button 
you can found this type of folw with jquery datatables plugins

Comment: @Rutunjsheladiya Thank You So much for ur valuable time and suggestion Thanks!!!